# C++ Exception Handling for ARM - Format of Generic Exception Handling Table Entries

Tags: c++, exception, arm, embedded

In [the exception handling ABI for the ARM architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0038a/IHI0038A_ehabi.pdf) it gives the format of the "ARM defined compact model" exception handling table entries, but no information about the "generic model" EHT entries beyond the fact that the first word is the offset of the personality routine.

Is there a document anywhere that gives the format of these entries beyond the first word? I can see there is a pattern to the first three words that occur in every entry, for example:

```
0553ff7f a908b100 ffff019c 80808000 92808080 00a48080 8000b680 80800000 ba808080 00848080 80000000
```

(byte order is reversed)

The second word seems to vary between several values for each entry, and the third word almost always ends with ffff (in one case I've seen it's 10ff). 
The first byte of the third word sometimes indicates the length of the entry (enough of the time that it's not a coincidence but not enough that it's a rule).

I see the words after the first 3 repeating regularly between entries but I have no idea how to interpret them either.

Documents I've looked at:

- http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/architecture/24525601.pdf
- https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/exceptions.pdf
- https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html

Comment: I think most of the information is in the PDF [exception handling ABI for the ARM architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0038a/IHI0038A_ehabi.pdf); *A table entry has a variable size. It encodes, in a vendor and language specific way, the actions required to propagate an exception through the function.*   The personality is a way to deal with the language's exception model.  For example, 'C' is very simple with *appendix C* saying typical is three instruction and at most seven.

Answer (score 0):

In section 4.3 of Exception Handling ABI for the ARM® Architecture it says:

> Generic — a table entry consists of a place-relative offset to a
>   function with an interface and run-time interaction protocol defined
>   by this EHABI, followed by data in a format private to that function.

So the format of the data in a generic entry is determined by the personality routine.  If your personality personality routine is named __gxx_personality_v0 then you can find the source in libstdc++ (eh_*.cc, especially eh_personality.cc)